# New to rails. Index action doesnt like my initialization method.. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I am completely new to rails and playing with the code to make pages work. 
The link *localhost:3000/zombies/1* works (show action) 
but localhost:3000/zombies (index action) doesn't. Below are my routes and controller:

**ROUTES ARE:**
 resources :zombies

**CONTROLLER is:**

```
 class ZombiesController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :get_zombie_params

   def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @zombies }
    end
   end

   def show
    @disp_zombie = increase_age @zombie, 15
    @zombie_new_age = @disp_zombie
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @zombie }
    end
  end

  def increase_age zombie, incr
   zombie = zombie.age + incr
  end

  def get_zombie_params
    @zombie=Zombie.find(params[:id])
    @zombies = Zombie.all

  end
end
```

Why is this?

Comment: can you paste the error you are receiving?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. What actually happens when you browse to /zombies/? Does an exception get thrown? Do you get a blank page? Further info would help us help you!

Comment: I get a page with the error:                                          **ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ZombiesController#index**                                              Couldn't find Zombie without an ID

Rails.root: C:/Sites/TwitterForZombies
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/zombies_controller.rb:85:in `get_zombie_params'

Comment: The problem is that you're running that before_filter on both routes. On show you can both call `Zombie.find(params[:id])` and `Zombie.all`. But in the index action, you don't have any params, so your `Zombie.find(params[:id]` is giving you the `ActiveRecord` error.

Comment: Thanks Mehul, Is there a way around this? I want to initialize both instance variables zombie and zombies in a seperate before method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Editing answer based on the comment

> I get a page with the error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in
>   ZombiesController#index Couldn't find Zombie without an ID Rails.root:
>   C:/Sites/TwitterForZombies Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full
>   Trace app/controllers/zombies_controller.rb:85:in `get_zombie_params'

The url, `localhost:3000/zombies` which calls `index` action does not include `id` parameter.

That's why the app is failing at `@zombie=Zombie.find(params[:id])`.

If you want to fix this issue, use `before_filter` on `show` action only.

`before_filter :get_zombie_params, only: :show`

And insert this into index action as I have originally suggested.

```
def index
  @zombies = Zombies.all
  ...
end
```

Comment: This isn't an issue - `@zombies` has already been assigned in the `before_filter`

Comment: Yes. That is already supposed to be taken care by the before filter

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because when you define `resources :zombies`, you get these routes :

```
/zombies
/zombies/:id
```

Therefore when navigating to `/zombies` you don't have a `params[:id]`, it is `nil`

`Zombie.find` method will raise an error if it can't find any record with the given id and halt further processing of your code.

You can use `Zombie.find_by_id` if you don't want an exception raised when there is no result.

But I don't think that this what you want here, you'd rather define a `get_zombie_by_id` method and a `get_all_zombies` method and separate the code from your `get_zombie_params`

Then you would have to define which method should be called before what action by changing your before_filter like so, in your case :

```
 before_filter :get_zombie_by_id, :only => :show
 before_filter :get_all_zombies, :only => :index
```

This way `Zombie.find(params[:id])` will only get called when on the show action.
You can also use `:except` to do the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

it does work because you need to send back ( to your index view ) the list of your zombies.
The get_zombie_params() excutes right but does not send @zombies to the index() action.

you need to do :

```
def index 
   @zombies = Zombie.all
   #... the rest of the code
end
```